# Web app not accessible in cellular data but accessible when on wifi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, networking

my react web app is not accessible in cellular data but i can accessible it when on wifi.

With cellular data i get the below message

"Webpage not available
Try again"

here is how my index.html looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
<meta name="description" content="description"/>
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha..." crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384..." crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title>App Name</title>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>
  You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your cellular network and the speed of it, your device might be having problems downloading the initial CDN content from the google apis. Cellphone networks would end up having a slower response time vs a wifi network. This might give you misleading errors due to javascript errors.

If you website is on a private network, your cellular device would definitely get that error.

Try using a site like https://jsfiddle.net/ to test your app so that you have a nice reliable location.

If you can provide more information and post it on jsfiddle, other users can check it on their cellular/mobile devices to diagnose your issue more.